# Usage of pronoun to refer a noun when there's a intervening text in between

Tags: grammar

Does the pronoun **they** fit the following sentence? I want to refer those 20 students by using **they**. There's an intervening text between the first and third sentence so does using **they** sound right and natural? Should I use **the workers** instead of **they**?

- There are 20 workers in my factory. This is a 20% increase from last year. **They** are very creative and honest.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate a noun and its pronoun by any length of text, as long as its unambiguous. As odd as it might be or sound if there was a 20 page gap, it wouldn't be or sound much less, if any, odd if you referred to "the workers" with a 20 page gap. But a sentence or a paragraph? No problem.

The contrapositive is also true. You can't use a pronoun in close proximity to its noun if it would be ambiguous.

"John told Pete that he would be in Texas next week." No!